# Is there a way to set a custom base version when merging with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I'm confronted with a Mercurial repository that has originally been a CVS repository. It has recently been migrated to Mercurial with cvs2hg.

The CVS repository had a couple of branches, lets call two of them "main" and "feature". "feature" has been branched off "main" a very long time ago. Between the branches, changes have frequently been "merged" by checking in changes committed in one branch into the other. There are frequently tagged "merge" revisions where "main" and "feature" have been equal.

When I try to do the first (real) merge in Mercurial, the three-way merge assumes that the "base" version is the revision when "feature" was originally branched off. This means that there is a lot of visual cluster with conflicts where "main" and "feature" are almost equivalent to each other but very different to the "base" version. This is so bad that the merge would take a very long time and would be error prone.

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell Mercurial that the base version is one of the tagged "merge" revisions, e.g.

hg up feature;
hg merge main --base "tag-xyz"

In this case, the merge would be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend fixing your recent history.  This is somewhat messy, but once finished, Mercurial's merges should work correctly out of the box.

First, find the most recent point at which the feature and main branches were exactly the same.  Merge the equivalent commits (merge main into feature).  This should create a new head with two parents (one from feature, one from main).  Furthermore, that head should be on the feature branch, not the main branch.  Since the commits are exactly the same, you should not experience conflicts.  Next, you will need to rebase the rest of the feature branch onto this head.

Suppose the new head is commit `abc`.  Again, this head has two parents, one of which is on the feature branch.  That feature parent has a second child, which is also on the feature branch.  Suppose that second child is commit `def`.  Then you can perform the rebase as follows:

```
hg phase -f -d 'def::'  # Unnecessary if you've never pushed
hg rebase -s def -d abc
```

**This will change the commit numbers** for `def` and all its descendants.  If you have multiple instances of the repository, they will need to undergo this same fixup, or you will need to re-clone them.  Otherwise, your repositories will get very messy when people push and pull.

Once you've done this, merging should "just work."